# What is the advantages of using perforce sync -p option?

Tags: synchronization, perforce

I read the [documentation](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_sync.html), and it says like this:-

> Populate a client workspace, but do not update the have list. Any file
>   that is already synced or opened is bypassed with a warning message.
>   This option is typically used for workspaces used in processes (such
>   as certain build or publication environments) where there is no need
>   to track the state of the workspace after it has first been synced.

But I don't quite understand the advantages(or disadvantages) of doing so.

Comment: It reduces the load on the server, at the cost of substantially more complicated client programming. If you aren't **certain** you need it, you don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example where this is useful: You have a build farm (e.g. 10 build servers); the 10 servers are clones: each has the same software installed, each can build your project, and each builds your project at the same local path (e.g. `C:\buildServer\projectFoo\`). To save yourself maintenance, you create a *single* P4 client (let's call it `clientFoo`) rather than 10 clients (one for each build server). You can use it on all the 10 build servers because `clientFoo` has its `Host` unspecified (in the client settings). Obviously, `clientFoo` maps your depot path to `C:\buildServer\projectFoo\`, which works well on all your 10 build boxes.

Now imagine your build servers used `p4 sync` rather than `p4 sync -p`. First, build server A would call `p4 sync` and get the Foo project on the local filesystem. Good. However, since it didn't use `-p`, it also updated the Perforce server, which now believes that project Foo is synced to the latest in `clientFoo`. If build server A syncs Foo again, it will get an incremental sync. Still good. However, if client B syncs Foo next, it will *also* get an incremental sync, i.e. it will only sync a couple files, or even nothing (if no files were modified since A synced Foo). That's wrong because B has nothing of Foo as yet! Syncing incrementally is non-sense.

The solution would be for build server B to call `p4 sync -f`: i.e. to ignore the "have" table (i.e. ignore what the Perforce server thinks that `clientFoo` already has) and force a full sync. That's certainly viable: all 10 build boxes could call `p4 sync -f` to work around the problem of unwanted incremental syncs. But each `p4 sync -f` will still update the Perforce server's "have" table, which is wasteful because we never use it (we always ignore it by using `-f`). So, to avoid maintaining the "have" table in vain, we can call `p4 sync -p` from all the build servers and never update the "have" table.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is similar to a `svn export`, you want to get all the files, but you don't intend to submit anything from this workspace.

For example for a continuous integration tool, that just want the file to build and execute some tests, and then will delete everything. I am not sure but it probably prevents to submit from this workspace (since you don't have a "have list") so it might be a safeguard.